# Passing variables from two NSWindows in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I am trying to update a label in an NSViewController from a NSWindowController.

Here is what I've done.

Created a protocol:

```
protocol PopoverProtocol: class {
    func SearchForIt(Query:String)
}
```

Created a function to update the label in the NSViewController

```
class PopoverController: NSViewController, PopoverProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: NSTextField!

    func SearchForIt(Query:String){
            Label.stringValue = Query
    }
}
```

Called the protocol and function from the NSWindowController

```
class TutorialViewController: NSWindowController, NSSearchFieldDelegate {

    weak var responder : PopoverProtocol?

    @IBAction override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification) {

    PopoVer.showRelativeToRect(SearchField.bounds, ofView: SearchField, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)

    responder?.SearchForIt(SearchField.stringValue)

    }
}
```

However nothing is happening. I am not getting any error messages, the function `SearchForIt` is just not being called.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in the `controlTextDidChange` function? If so did you confirm that `responder` is not nil?

Comment: I just checked and `responder` is nil ... Thanks for that. But how come it's nil ?

Comment: No idea... I'm not very familiar with ios development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A protocol is adopted by a class as you did in your second block of code above. Now your view controller has to implement the SearchForIt method and then your view controller can take the call, not a separately defined object.

In your controlTextDidChange, replace responder with your viewcontroller instance.